# SAST_EXCLUDED_PATHS wont ignore my directories

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, sast

I am trying to ignore few directories that are creating thousands of vulnerabilities in my repo's Vulnerability Report.
But I am unable to do so...

---

Below is part of my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file

```
include:
  - template: Dependency-Scanning.gitlab-ci.yml
  - template: SAST.gitlab-ci.yml
  - template: Dependency-Scanning.gitlab-ci.yml

sast:
  stage: test
  variables:
      SAST_EXCLUDED_PATHS: schemas,src/app/schemas,src/assets,resources,*.min.js
      SECURE_LOG_LEVEL: "debug"
```

Vulnerability report successfully gets updated which shows my exact master commit, but does not respect my exclusions.

[image: screenshot]

Can someone please help me in this ?